# Help needed: Finding a string pattern and replacing it with an empty string

Tags: c#, regex

My input string is:

"-->
**Job Title:** Test text

**JobId:** 56565-116503

**City:** San Diego

**State:** CA

**Zip Code:** 92108

**Description:** 
            We are recruiting for a Controller to oversee all accounting and finance for a growing manufacturing company.  We are looking for someone who is hands on full cycle accounting.

http://www.testurl.com</apply></email>http://test.xml</OriginalFetchUrl>http://test.html</OriginalWrapUrl></clientHtml>-->"

I need to extract following string using C#/Regular expressions:

1."We are recruiting for a Controller to oversee all accounting and finance for a growing manufacturing company.  We are looking for someone who is hands on full cycle accounting."

Can I please get help with the code?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string pattern = @"JobId:.*?City:.*?State:.*?Zip\sCode:\s\d+\s";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "");
```

Result: Senior Accountant - Growing Public Company Description: Multi-faceted multi-national corporation...

EDIT: comment based on your edit.

The above regex should handle multiple Description items. Example:

```
string input = "Senior Accountant - Growing Public Company JobId: 34441-345877 City: Santa Diego State: CA Zip Code: 93117 Description: 1st description here Description: Multi-faceted multi-national corporation...";
```

Replacement result is: "Senior Accountant - Growing Public Company **Description:** 1st description here **Description:** Multi-faceted multi-national corporation..."

Comment: Ed: I believe the above regex handles multiple descriptions, per your recent edit. I updated with a sample input string and the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
 JobId: [^\s]+\sCity: .*?\sState: [A-Z]{2}\sZip Code: [^\s]+\sDescription:
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated regex:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"JobId:.*?City:.*?State:.*?Zip\s+Code:.*?(?=Description:)","");
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer...i've modified my questions.Appreciate if you could reply to that as well.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to extract the `Description` field values, perhaps replacing all the unwanted stuff with empty strings is not the best solution.

Assuming your question can be turned around to ask, "how do I extract the Description field values?", the regular expression that you need can be as simple as:

```
string pattern = @" Description: (.+)$";
```

Then you can use a `Regex.Match/NextMatch` loop to extract all descriptions.

Answer (score 0):

IF all of your descriptions separate the address from the description with "Description:", then you could go old-school:

```
string separator = "Description:";
int startIndex = originalText.IndexOf(separator)+separator.Length;
string newText = originalText.Substring(startIndex);
```